# CR2032 vs LIR2032 vs Capacitance Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, supercapacitor

I have an Android TV Box device that does not retain the date and time. Turns out there is not real time clock backup (RTC battery). There are 3 options to solve this.

1. Capacitance battery
2. CR2032
3. LIR2032

How effective is a capacitance battery compared to other 2 options? I am looking for something that I would not need to replace till next 3 to 4 years once installed. I have installed CR2032 in one of the other Android device that I have. It has been working fine for about 10 months now but I highly doubt it will last for 3 to 4 year though.

I am not sure how quickly would the capacitor drain if the device does not get power supply for a day or two, or will the charge last till two days for that matter.

I did a quick search but could not find a comparison anywhere.

1. Which would be the best option out of the 3? Or is there any option?
2. If capacitor, then what would be the specs.?
3. If LIR is the way to go then do I need any other external circuit for it?

Comment: Is there a way of charging the first or third options?

Comment: As per the answer already given, I see no reason why the CR2032 won't easily last 5-10 years. The other two options you've mentioned are good in their own way, but only if you have the ability to charge them.

Answer (score 3):

> I have installed CR2032 in one of the other Android device that I have. It has been working fine for about 10 months now but I highly doubt it will last for 3 to 4 year though.

Why? The RTC should only require about 1 µA, which is in the same order of magnitude as the *self discharge* rate of a CR2032 coin cell. You can expect it to work for about 5 to 10 years - depending on the *quality* of the cell itself, so YMMV.

LIR2032 may have too high a voltage (4.2V fully charged), and both LIR2032 and capacitor need *charging* circuitry.

Comment: I am not well educated about batteries and electronic circuits and also as per the vendor from where I bought the battery told me it would last for about 1 year. So I have doubts it would last for 3 to 4 years. Btw, I am using Maxell battery - http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61tLrWoIzrL._SX425_.jpg

Also it would be great if you could you share more information on charging circuit. Will I have to add a separate circuit to the Android box motherboard?